# Is there a need to create virtual environments inside SageMaker (given SageMaker notebook instances are already separate conda environments)?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, virtualenv, conda, amazon-sagemaker

It is common practice to create virtual environments on any Python project, to avoid global installation and package collision errors, and of course keep track of Python versions across projects.

Amazon SageMaker already comes with conda environments. In fact, SageMaker notebook instances are already separate conda environments. So, this begs the question (I think), does it make sense to create a virtual environment inside an AWS SageMaker notebook when working on a Python project inside SageMaker?

What if I want to use a specific version of Python...well SageMaker allows us to simply change the kernal. So is that good enough in terms of the advantages that a separate virtual environment brings?

What about package organization? Knowing exactly the packages you need to run your code in case someone else needs to run it on their machines is an obvious advantage of using virtual environments. Does SageMaker help with this if I don't setup a virtual environment?

So, do SageMaker users have to run things like:

```
conda create --name myenv
```

or

```
python3 -m venv env
```

Answer (score 0):

SageMaker provides you a list of pre-built environments for the common ML frameworks and versions to get started. There's no specific package organization feature if you do not set up a virtual environment. So, if your project needs a specific set of packages and versions that need to be reproducible and shared, you're better off creating a custom conda environment.
Some additional documentation here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi-add-external.html

Comment: I have successfully run PyTorch/graphviz from a notebook instance in SageMaker by installing pip torchviz. The SageMaker 3.9 PyTorch kernel already has graphviz-0.20.1 so it went smoothly. However, when I use Sagemaker Studio I get a `failed to execute PosixPath('dot'), make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH` error. Somehow the studio version is different. What do you recommend?